# TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

Hi I am doing some testing for now , I want to fix robot robot_test , let it go pass, I continue face error message of title detail you can check 4. Result, below are some info and what I try

Please help me how to fix TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

#### 1. robot_test_features.robot

```
### robot_test_features.robot ###
*** Settings ***
Resource    robot_test_keywords.robot
*** Test Cases ***
BitoPro limitations and fees Page
    User will see VIP0 twdVolume are "3000000"
```

#### 2. robot_test_keywords.robot

```
### robot_test_keywords.robot ###
*** Settings ***
Library     robot_test_steps.py
*** Keywords ***
User will see VIP0 twdVolume are "${twdVolumeValue}"
    verify_vip0_twd_volume  ${twdVolumeValue}
```

#### 3. robot_test_steps.py

```
def verify_vip0_twd_volume(_tradingFeeRateDict):
    assert _tradingFeeRateDict[0]["twdVolume"] == "3000000"
    print(type(_tradingFeeRateDict[0]["twdVolume"])) #<class 'str'>
    print(_tradingFeeRateDict[0]["twdVolume"])#3000000
```

#### 4. result

```
➜  ~ robot robot_test

==============================================================================
Robot Test
==============================================================================
Robot Test.Robot Test Features
==============================================================================
BitoPro limitations and fees Page                                     | FAIL |
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Robot Test.Robot Test Features                                        | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Robot Test                                                            | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

i think i am really close to answer but i always get error message on TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

this is what i try
(1)
`print(type(_tradingFeeRateDict[0]["twdVolume"]))`

> output #<class 'str'>, yes this is str

(2)
`print(_tradingFeeRateDict[0]["twdVolume"])`

> output is 3000000, str is match i expect
> (3)
> `assert str(_tradingFeeRateDict[0]["twdVolume"]) == "3000000"`

> just double str , still get error on robot robot_test

(4) on python3 unit test

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    _response_text = API('https://api.bitopro.com/v3/provisioning/limitations-and-fees')
    _tradingFeeRateDict = parse(_response_text)
    verify_vip0_twd_volume(_tradingFeeRateDict)
```

> NO any error expect is correct

i really need help (1)why python3 go correct but (2) robot robot_test go fail (3) how to fix
many thank

Comment: what is the question exactly ?

Comment: How to fix this error message, I want command:robot robot_test Go pass

Comment: What is `_tradingFeeRateDict[0]`? The error suggests that it's a string, which is why you can't use `"twdVolume"` as an index.

Answer (score 1):

from what I can tell the function from snippet 3:

```
def verify_vip0_twd_volume(_tradingFeeRateDict):
```

seemingly takes a dictionary ('dict' int '_tradingFeeRateDict') as argument however based on the function body it should be a list of dictionaries.

However in your snippet 1 you use the string "3000000":

```
User will see VIP0 twdVolume are "3000000"
```

...and not a list of dicts, thus what verify_vip0_twd_volume tries to execute is:

```
assert "3000000"[0]["twdVolume"] == "3000000"  # TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'
```